# Does Mongoid load the entire user object when the devise current_user variable is used?

Tags: mongodb, devise, mongoid

I've embedded all the activities for a user and let's say most user has tens of thousands of activities associated with them. When checking the **current_user** in my controller code, does Mongoid load the entire user object containing all the embedded activity records? My gut feeling tells me no but I'd really want to confirm it so I can sleep better at night. :) Thank you!

Below is a short version of the User class.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :activities
end
```

---

EDIT

Let me clarify why I'm particularly interested to see if the entire object is loaded when using current_user. Since the activities are embedded in the user document, and most users have thousands of records, each full load would be expensive if all I want is just to check whether the user is signed in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. Devise requests the entire model when authenticating, so Mongoid will give you access to `activities` if you call `current_user.activities`.

Comment: But in views, sometimes I just want to check whether the user is signed in so I can display different modules according to whether the user is signed in or not. Seems that check is super expensive if lots of data are embedded to it. Should I link the activities instead of embedding them?

Comment: The problem is mostly that while you're not wrong, fixing it would mean monkey patching multiple areas of Devise to work around it. You could look at the default scope option in Mongoid and see about excluding `activities` by default which mean get you what you want without monkey patching a few areas in Devise. Alternatively, you could dig through the `database_authenticable` module to find the monkey patch points.